# Display cell with vertical text using EPPlus

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

Using EPPlus, how can i change a cells text to display as a vertical text like this,

[image: Sample]

In excel, you can do this by clicking on this button when setting cell orientation,

[image: Excel orientation]

I'm trying to play around with the `.TextRotation` but this does not achieve what I want, setting it to something like 180 degrees will give me something like this,

[image]

`ws.Cells[row, 2].Style.TextRotation = 180;`, `.TextRotation` only accepts an integer value so I was wondering how I can get the "Text" buttons value,

Comment: I was intrigues by this and stacked text like you wanted in Excel and then opened that file in C#, using EPPlus. Cell with stacked text has `VerticalAlignment` set to bottom and `TextRotation` value set to 255. When I tried to set `TextRotation` value to 255 programatically, I got ` ArgumentOutOfRangeException` (which can be seen in [source](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus/blob/master/EPPlus/Style/ExcelStyle.cs), line 181. So, try to contact EPPlus developer. :)

Comment: @Nino thanks, I'll do that. Also, I never thought of manually creating the excel file and reading it using EPPlus, so thanks for that, will make my life easier when trying to create excels with a lot of formatting.

Comment: glad I could help you; if not with an answer, then at least with a comment :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its definitely a bug you found.  There is a way but it is pretty ugly.  You can use the `StyleID` created by the cell when you change it to anything other than the default:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Text_Rotate_Test()
{
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57603348/display-cell-with-vertical-text-using-epplus

    var fileInfo = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\Text_Rotate_Test.xlsx");
    if (fileInfo.Exists)
        fileInfo.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo))
    {
        var workbook = pck.Workbook;
        var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        var cell = worksheet.Cells[1, 1];

        cell.Value = "Test Text Value";

        //Trigger epplus to create a new style specific for the cell.
        //This needs to be done even thought it will be overridden in 
        //order to ref by index.  But have to be careful not to step
        //on other styles so make it as unique as it needs to be.
        cell.Style.TextRotation = 180;

        //Make sure the update the xml before looking up by index
        workbook.Styles.UpdateXml();
        workbook.Styles.CellXfs[cell.StyleID].TextRotation = 255;

        pck.Save();
    }
}
```

Which gives this:

[image]

Comment: well done. I thought that this might work, but I would surely miss stuff like `workbook.Styles.UpdateXml();`.

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I was trying to rebuild a dll with updated code and wasn't successful, this certainly saved me a lot of time trying to rebuild the project.